# Fullcalendar: Select on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar 2.9.1 and fullcalendar-scheduler 1.3.3

First off, this is an amazing calendar plugin, thanks Adam! :)

My main issue right now is that I can't seem to get the cell selection working on touch devices.

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

I *eventually* figured out that it looks at the longPressDelay value. This is no good for me - I need the longpress behaviour for moving/resizing events (so people don't accidentally do this when trying to scroll a busy calendar), but I definitely don't want any delay when trying to select a cell on mobile, because it's pretty unintuitive (took me days to think to try it).

Also, even with longPressDelay set to 0 (which I don't want), I'm seeing that the cell gets selected then immediately unselected. The same issue is also reported here: [Fix mobile day selection in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797059/fix-mobile-day-selection-in-fullcalendar):

> "This seems to work fine on desktop, but on mobile it selects the day
>   for a fraction of a second then gets un-selected immediately for some
>   reason."

So... to summarise I need:

1. instant empty cell selection (cross device), and
2. longPressDelay to
   still work for dragging/resizing as it currently does.

Is this possible? Thanks!

**Note:** I feel cell selection is much more important on touch devices because of people's "fat fingers". It needs to be clear which cell you've selected before proceeding to the next step.